# How to change #theme function of specific menu items?(not all of them)

Tags: routes, theming

In my site I have a menu array that is printed in my page via drupal_render function.

I checked the array via `krumo()`* function and I found each item (link) has a property names `'#theme'` with value `'menu_link__main_menu'`

If I use function **`theme_menu_link()`** in template.php (in theme folder) it will change all menu items but I don't want to change the theme of all menus. I want to change only specific item theme function.

So before using print `drupal_render()` function, I changed the #theme property of my selected link item directly.

For example

```
$menu_array[218]['#theme'] = 'custom_theme_function';
```

** 218 is the key of one of the link item in menu_array

but in this step, I don't know how should I define **custom_theme_function** in my theme template.php

I defined `THEMENAME_custom_theme_function ($variables) {}` in my template.php 
* THEMENAME is replaced by name of my theme

but it doesn't work. I don't know if I want to set a custom theme wrapper for specific menu items, How can I do that?

Comment: You also need to implement [`hook_theme`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) and declare your theming function to Drupal. Otherwise it will skip your theme override because the function doesn't exist (as far as Drupal's concerned)

Comment: You mean I should create a module for that?

Comment: Nope you can implement it in your template.php: "Register a module (or **theme's**) theme implementations"

Comment: I found that my problem is related to theme function registration because In Log section I see this alert " Theme hook custom_theme_function not found." Can you guide me how can I register my theme function in template.php

Comment: Ok. I made some progression in my issue. I could register my custom function via this code: #### function blue_theme() {return array('custom_theme_function' => array('variables' => array()),);} #### and function work. but variables is null in calling function. I don't know what should I put in front of variables to access menu item.

Comment: I could find my solution. theme function is registered but I receive this warning message. 'Notice: Undefined index: render element in theme() (line 1081. every thing works fine but I don't know why this warning happened and I can't solve it.